# Core Data IBTool Hang

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, ibtool

I'm wading into Core Data, and starting with the Core Data books by Marcus S. Zarra, I've uploaded the sample (so far) to [Grokking-Recipes](https://github.com/slashlos/Grokking-Recipes.git) on github. My intent was to create a Swift sample but so far it's Objective-C.

The problem is getting it to compile. The ibtool uses all memory until I kill off the Xcode and process(es).  It's pretty simplistic but I'm presuming something is wrong.

Of course I'm using newer tools - Xcode8.3 / OS X 10.2.5, so there've been a few deprecations etc but otherwise it follows the book's sample.

Perhaps something new must be done to compile this ?

Comment: This is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+hangs+binding)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I feel better with the silly exercise; I just drop that binding for now.